# Converting base of probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I have a probability distribution $\frac{(p_0,p_1,...,p_s)}{a}$ where $\sum_s \frac{p_s}{a} = 1$ and $p_s \in \mathbb{N}$ that I want to convert to another distribution $\frac{(q_0,q_1,...,q_s)}{b}$ while preserving some conditions:

$$\sum_s \frac{q_s}{b} = 1$$
$$\forall s \space p_s > 0 \Rightarrow q_s > 0$$
$$\forall s \space \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{q_s}{b} = \frac{p_s}{a}$$

The first two are mandatory, but are not guaranteed by $q_s = \left \lfloor \frac{a \cdot p_s}{b}\right \rfloor$, $q_s = \left \lfloor \frac{a \cdot p_s}{b}\right \rceil$, or $q_s = \left \lceil \frac{a \cdot p_s}{b}\right \rceil$. How can I do this?

Note: This is for an implementation of [rANS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2540.pdf).

Comment: Are $p_s$ and $q_s$ integers?

Comment: yes, they are integers

Answer (score 1):

For $b<a$, the conversion might be impossible, e.g., if $p_j=1$ for all $j \le m$. So we assume that $b \ge a$.

Define $\Psi_k:=\sum_{j=1}^k p_j$ and
$Q_k:=\lfloor b\Psi_k/a \rfloor$ for $k=0,1,\ldots, m.$ In particular, $Q_0=\Psi_0=0$.
Finally, take $q_k:=Q_k-Q_{k-1}$ for $k=1,\ldots, m.$ Observe that

- $\Psi_m=a$, so $Q_m=b$.
- If $p_k>0$, then $b\Psi_k/a \ge  b\Psi_{k-1}/a$, so  $q_k=Q_k-Q_{k-1} \ge 1$.
- Suppose that $a$ and all the $p_j$ are fixed, and $b$ is growing. Then  $Q_k=Q_k(b)$ satisfy $|Q_k/b-\Psi_k/a| \le 1/b$. Therefore, as $b \to \infty$, we have $Q_k/b \to \Psi_k/a$ and $q_k/b \to p_k/a$.

Comment: $a$ is almost always greater than $b$, but it is not impossible because $n$ is always less than $b$. $n = 2^8$ and $b = 2^{15}$.

Comment: $n$ does not appear in your original question. Are $q_s$ integers? Then the task is impossible if  $a>b$ and all $p_i$ are 1.